# ERRORSQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Al intentar arreglarlo le quite el espacio en

$sentencia -> bindParam(**':autor_id'**, $id_usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);

pero me salio otro error:

Notice: Undefined index: titulo on line (**debajo de new entrada** *$fila['titulo'*)

```
if(isset($conexion)){
        try{
            $sql = "SELECT a.id, a.autor_id, a.url, a.texto, a.fecha, a.activa, COUNT(b.id) AS 'cantidad_comentarios' ";
            $sql .= "FROM entradas a ";
            $sql .= "LEFT JOIN comentarios b ON a.id = b.entrada_id ";
            $sql .= "WHERE a.autor_id = :autor_id ";
            $sql .= "GROUP BY a.id ";
            $sql .= "ORDER BY a.fecha DESC";                
            $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
            $sentencia -> bindParam(' :autor_id', $id_usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sentencia -> execute();
            $resultado = $sentencia -> fetchAll();

            if(count($resultado)) {
                foreach ($resultado as $fila){
                    $entradas_obtenidas = array(
                         new Entrada($fila['id'],$fila['autor_id'],
                         $fila['url'],$fila['titulo'],$fila['texto'],$fila['fecha'],$fila['activa']),
                    $fila['cantidad_comentarios']
                    );                        
                }                    
            }
        }catch(PDOException $ex){
            print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer error se debe a que tienes un espacio en tu instrucción

`$sentencia -> bindParam(' :autor_id', $id_usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

**debe de ir sin el espacio**

```
$sentencia -> bindParam(':autor_id', $id_usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Ahora bien, el nuevo error que te genera es porque en tu sentencia `select` no estas trayendo la columna de nombre `titulo` que quieres utilizar en tu objeto `new Entrada()` solo agrega esta columna a tu query

```
$sql = "SELECT a.id, a.autor_id, a.url, a.titulo, a.texto, a.fecha, a.activa, COUNT(b.id) AS 'cantidad_comentarios' ";
$sql .= "FROM entradas a ";
$sql .= "LEFT JOIN comentarios b ON a.id = b.entrada_id ";
$sql .= "WHERE a.autor_id = :autor_id ";
$sql .= "GROUP BY a.id ";
$sql .= "ORDER BY a.fecha DESC";
```

Comment: gracias ;) no había notado el segundo

Comment: @AlessandroInocente si la respuesta te ayudo no olvides marcarla como respuesta correcta :D